# Why did GA4 product link stopped working?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

My GA4 property stopped sending data since 3 days to my bigquery tables.
The configuration has not changed and have been running for the last 4 month without any issues.
I have not reach the export limit (the property is at 4% of 1M events limits)

Would you know where could it come from ?

Best

Answer (score 0):

Standard properties have a daily BigQuery Export limit of 1 million events. If your property consistently exceeds the export limit, the daily BigQuery export will be paused and previous days’ exports will not be reprocessed.

Property editors and administrators will receive an email notification each time a property they manage exceeds the daily limit. That notification will indicate when their export will be paused if action is not taken. Additionally, if a standard property significantly exceeds the one-million-event daily limit, Analytics may pause daily exports immediately. If you receive a notification, please leverage the data-filtering options (data-stream export and event-exclusion) to decrease the volume of events exported each day and ensure the daily export continues to operate.